# In Visual Studio, my Winforms program is not supporting interfaces. How can I make it support them?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

I've used Visual Studio in the past e.g. Visual Studio 2015, and prior, and not run into a problem like this.

I have Visual Studio 2019, and created a Winforms program and get this error

> Default interface implementation is not available in c# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or higher

[image]

In the past, I used C# when it was c# 5.0 or earlier like C# v3  or C# v4, and I never ran into this.

I notice that Visual Studio 2019 offers two types of Winforms programs, .NET Framework and .NET Core

[image]

That error happens with the .NET Framework ones.

When I create a Winforms project picking .NET Core, then I don't get that error. I don't really know what the difference is between these two. But why does a Winforms program picked with .NET framework not support interfaces, but with .NET Core would?

I found one webpage said I need to install .net core 3, I did and the program (which was based on .NET framework) still didn't work.

Am I not meant to be creating Winforms programs based on .NET Framework? And only with .NET Core?

When I have a Winforms program based on .NET Framework, how am I supposed to get it to work?

I looked at downloading C# 8  I see this link https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/take-c-8-0-for-a-spin/ mentions .NET Core 3, though I think I already installed .NET Core 3.  And the problem is with Winforms programs based on the .NET Framework, rather than ones based on .NET Core

Comment: look in your project settings...

Comment: @DanielA.White look for what? to change what to what? and what section? application? build? build events? package? debug?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to declare the following interface:

```
interface abcd
{
    static int abcd;
}
```

You're using .NET Framework, which defaults to C# 7.3. In C# 7.3, an interface cannot contain static members, or fields, so this is wrong twice. Before default interface implementations were added in C# 8.0, this would have been a different error; probably one telling you that interfaces cannot contain fields. After C# 8.0, however, it is possible to do this sort of thing as part of a default implementation, so now the error assumes you were trying to do that, and tells you what version of C# you need to enable in order to do so.

If you weren't trying to add a default implementation, then you can fix your code by making that field into a property, and making that property not static.

```
interface abcd
{
    int abcd { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: no error here in the .NET Core one,  https://i.imgur.com/TaYToAz.png   and that has a static field.

Comment: though the getter/setter solution you mention works

Comment: Core probably defaults to C#8, where the syntax is valid

Comment: @HansKeﬆing you're right, and looks like target framework has defaulted to c# 8.0 for quite a while  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version  `.NET Standard 2.1 C# 8.0`  and  `NET Core 3.x C# 8.0`  I see ".net framework" is quite old.. then microsoft named their thing/framework  .net standard, then .net core. with successive revisions

Comment: Yuo write "An interface cannot contain static members, or fields" <-- Though it can in C# 8  https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7SQU.png

Comment: @barlop What I meant was that prior to C# 8.0, it could not. Even with default implementations, fields on an interface are subtly different to fields on a class.

Comment: @anaximander well can you amend.correct this sentence "An interface cannot contain static members, or fields, so this is wrong twice."  so that it's correct/clear? Thanks  You have a sentence there that is wrong itself, and yet is saying something else is wrong twice!

Answer (score 1):

info from vivek, hans and anax helped..

so there's two ways of creating a winforms application in VS 2019, one is .NET Core, one is .NET Framework (as we see looking at the image in the question)

Each is associated with a different version of the C# language.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

```
Target framework    version C#      language version  
.NET Core           3.x              C# 8.0
.NET Core           2.x              C# 7.3
.NET Standard       2.1              C# 8.0
.NET Standard       2.0              C# 7.3
.NET Standard       1.x              C# 7.3
.NET Framework      all              C# 7.3
```

`.NET Framework` is the old name for the framework / name for an older framework, and `.NET Core` is more recent.

So it's probably better to create them choosing `.NET Core`

And if creating a .NET Core one, then the language used is C# 8.

Whereas when creating it with .NET Framework, then the language used is C# 7.3

Both don't allow instance variables in an interface but the more recent one (c# 8), which is used with .NET Core, does allow static variables in an interface.

[image]

[image]

VS 2015 used the old one, .NET Framework.

In VS 2015, I must have just used getters and setters e.g.

`int abcd { get; set; }`

Which of course you can still do with the newer one, the .NET Core one.

Answer (score 0):

Error is pretty clear that it’s only allowed in C# 8.0 or greater.

And C# 8.0 supports .net core

.net frameworks don’t support version greater then C# 7.3.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version#defaults

Comment: why would I have not run into this with VS 2015? I see that VS 2015 only seemed to have one winforms  option https://i.imgur.com/PIkcSQD.png  Was that .NET framework, or .NET Core?

Comment: so it's .net framework in VS 2015, so then why didnt I run into issues/this issue, when creating interfaces in winforms programs when I used VS 2015?

Comment: it does not even work in VS 2015 also. I have checked it gives "errorCS0106 The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item". Yes now they have changed the error message because they are supporting in c# and giving you hint to use C#8

Comment: what about without static, is that also an error?  if so, then I guess maybe when I did interfaces in VS 2015, I did them with getter and setter always like `int abcd { get; set; }`